# how to get the callback event when the users click on ads in admob new Native Ads

Tags: admob, native

Previously, when we were using Admob native ads, we could normally handle the "user clicks the ads" in the onclick callback event.
[the callback event of old Native Ads](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MUxbd.jpg)

We recently tested and found that admob provided a new form of advertising(Native Ads which needs secondary confirmation).
[the new Native ads](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9GVX4.png)

In this new form of Native Ads, when the user clicks on the ad, Admob sdk no longer callback the onclick event. Now we don’t know how to get the callback event when the users click on ads.
[the callback event of new Native Ads](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wlJy6.jpg)

Can we use the OnAdopened callback event or OnAdLeftApplication callback event in the New Native Ads when we can not get the OnClick callback event??